# word.sub-word.sub-sub-word

Tags: c#

I am new to programming so I don't know what the terminology is and I apologize. I want to be able to write something that looks like this:

```
Label Label1 = new Label();
Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

But with my own objects:

```
Reciept ReciptForAirPlaneTicket = new Reciept();
ReciptForAirPlaneTicket.MOP = MOP.CreditCard.Visa("4111111111111111|0815");

Reciept ReciptForFood = new Reciept();
ReciptForFood.MOP = MOP.CreditCard.MasterCard("4222222222222222|0917");

Reciept ReciptForClothes = new Reciept();
ReciptForClothes.MOP = MOP.Cash;

Reciept ReciptForTools = new Reciept();
ReciptForTools.MOP = MOP.Check("12345");
```

I really am not trying to be lazy, but I have been looking for almost a day now and I don't even know what to look for. I think I need to make at least a class but also a struct or something called enum but I really don't know.

I am using C#.

Comment: I hope that's not a real credit card number :)

Comment: There really isn't a question here. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jb: It's not. It's not even [a valid fake](http://www.ihwy.com/labs/jquery-validate-credit-card-extension.aspx) (the one tvanfosson edited in is)

Comment: I told you I don't know the words but I obviously was trying to find out how to make the parts to do my example. I asked it well enough that dbaseman was able to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an unusual approach to me, but to get the exact syntax, you could create a kind of factory pattern using a static class MOP.

```
public class MethodOfPayment
{
    public enum enumCardType { Visa, Mastercard };
    public enum enumPaymentType { CreditCard, Cash };

    public string Number { get; set; }
    public enumPaymentType PaymentType { get; set; }
    public enumCardType CardType { get; set; }
}

public static class MOP
{
    public static class CreditCard
    {
        public static MethodOfPayment Visa(string number)
        {
            return new MethodOfPayment() { 
                Number = number,
                PaymentType = MethodOfPayment.enumPaymentType.CreditCard,
                CardType = MethodOfPayment.enumCardType.Visa
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Repeat for the other types, and then instantiate as required.

```
ReciptForAirPlaneTicket.MOP = MOP.CreditCard.Visa("4111111111111111|0517");
```

Comment: That's is not bad, only I can't seem to use the get. I get an error saying I can't use it as a statement.

Comment: Juts take the get and it's braces out. Minor slip by @dbaseman

Comment: @Makai ah yeah, sorry about that.  Fixed it.

Comment: Adbaseman you might as well just delete the old part of the answer, unless there's some reason to keep it I am not seeing?

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes, good point.  Honestly not sure why I left that there.